# How to highlight selected tab's icon in tab and view pager implementation android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-tablayout, android-icons

I want the output as it is shown in this gif

[image]

I implemented tabs as mentioned in this tutorial https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter . I came across this tutorial https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout/ , but it has a copyright and licensing on it. But I would like to know if the same could be achieved using in built android functionalities

Comment: @Charuka The question is how to programmatically (Writing java code and using android framework) to achieve something like above.

Answer (score 2):

This seems fairly easy.
You need two set's of each icon. One grey and one white.

When you select an item [(TabItem)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html) , [change the icon](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) of tab to the white one, and change the icon of last selected tab to grey one.